# How to get JPG file length in bytes AFTER resizing and compressing the image with Imagick in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I have the following code:

```
$im = new Imagick($original_image_filename);

$original_width = $im->getImageWidth();
$original_height = $im->getImageHeight();
$original_length = $im->getImageLength();

if($original_width > 300) {

    $im->scaleImage(300, 0);    // max size for images is 300px wide

}

$scaled_width = $im->getImageWidth();
$scaled_height = $im->getImageHeight();
$scaled_length = $im->getImageLength();

$compression_quality = 20;

$im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_quality);

$compressed_length = $im->getImageLength();
```

`$original_width`, `$original_height`, and `$original_length` all work as expected but `$scaled_length` and `$compressed_length` are all set to 0.

What can I do to get the length of the image after scaling and compressing it?

I need to know as I want to limit thumbnail file size.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the image to string and get its length:

```
$finalSize = strlen($im->__toString());
```

See more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.tostring.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the thumbnail size of a JPEG, you may be better off just telling ImageMagick to do that for you:

```
$imagick->setOption('jpeg:extent', '86kb');
```

It will then set the quality as high as possible for you whilst respecting your maximum size.